# TFS Eclipse Plugin - Can't Select Query

Tags: eclipse, tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

When trying to check a change into TFS with TEE (v14) I get an error if I try and select a query.  The error is,

```
Unable to run query
The query "My Work Items" can't be run because of the following error with the query:
The specified variable does not exist.  The error is caused by <<@project>>.
```

This is environmental though as I have another VM which is perfectly fine but uses a slightly old eclipse (Kepler).  This to me implies that actually there is nothing wrong with the query!!  I have compared the configuration in .microsoft but with no joy.

I can check in by using the task ID directly but would like to be able to see my tasks.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Redhat 6.7
Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)
TEE Plugin v14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in current version Team Explorer Everywhere 2015 (14.0.1) which causes the "specified variable does not exist" error message.

As a workaround, you can either: 1) run the query prior to opening the "Check In" dialog, or 2) add the work item to the dialog by entering its ID.

(check David Staheli's post in the bottom of this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/07/06/team-explorer-everywhere-2015-rtm.aspx)